# Phrase for dirtying the room

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What to say while asking a person not to dirty *(verb)* my room?

The context in which I'm using this sentence is that the person who's going into my room has a habit of throwing wrappers anywhere and making a mess of the room.

Here what will be the correct substitute for dirty, as dirty seems a bit awkward?

Answer (score 3):

"Dirty" is the wrong word to describe leaving wrappers.  But you already have the right one: mess. You should use "messy".  Dirty relates to, for example getting mud on the floor.

And the verb is "to mess up", or "make a mess of"

> Please don't mess up my room by leaving out wrappers everywhere.

Comment: A related expression is “Clean up after yourself.” *I don’t mind if you want to use my desk for your video calls, as long as you clean up after yourself when you’re done.*

Answer (score 0):

If the material you are worried about is not normally present I suggest something like "Pick up your trash", most of the usual phrases about a room (like "trashing a room"), at least to me, are about messing up stuff that is normally there.

"Pick up your trash" on the other hand applies anywhere and is about the trash (the real problem) rather than where it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> Please keep the room clean and tidy.

You don't want to mention words like *messy*, *dirty*, *disorderly*, *untidy* because they might conjure up certain images in your friend's head and entice them to act accordingly ;)